# Split flac files using cue: shnsplit failed

Tags: audio

I use this command to split flac files using cue, and it worked for all files:

```
ffmpeg -i *.flac temp.wav
shnsplit -o flac -f *.cue -t "%n %t" temp.wav
mkdir bk; mv *.flac bk/
cuetag.sh *.cue *.flac
```

However, recently I encountered some files in a Touhou OST music collection, and shnsplit did not work:

```
shnsplit: error: m:ss.ff format can only be used with CD-quality files
```

ffprobe *.flac:

```
Output #0, wav, to 'Touhou Reiiden ~ Highly Responsive to Prayers.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.38.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.70.100 pcm_s16le
```

Cue:

```
REM GENRE Soundtrack
REM DATE 1996-11-xx
PERFORMER "太田順也(ZUN)"
TITLE "東方靈異伝　～ Highly Responsive to Prayers"
REM REPLAYGAIN_ALBUM_GAIN -5.59 dB
REM REPLAYGAIN_ALBUM_PEAK 0.987305
FILE "Touhou Reiiden ~ Highly Responsive to Prayers.flac" FLAC
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "A Sacred Lot"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -6.14 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.985352
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "永遠の巫女"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -6.18 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.987030
    INDEX 01 03:08:29
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "陰陽　～ The Positive and Negative"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -6.35 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.985962
    INDEX 01 06:18:55
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "神へ捧げる魂　～ Highly Responsive to Prayers"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -3.59 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.957123
    INDEX 01 08:20:57
  TRACK 05 AUDIO
    TITLE "東方怪奇談"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -4.25 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.936157
    INDEX 01 11:26:67
  TRACK 06 AUDIO
    TITLE "天使伝説"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -3.57 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.867889
    INDEX 01 14:25:32
  TRACK 07 AUDIO
    TITLE "Oriental Magician"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -6.00 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.985138
    INDEX 01 20:32:70
  TRACK 08 AUDIO
    TITLE "破邪の小太刀"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -6.08 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.942291
    INDEX 01 24:13:05
  TRACK 09 AUDIO
    TITLE "魔鏡"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -5.11 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.862610
    INDEX 01 26:22:38
  TRACK 10 AUDIO
    TITLE "the Legend of KAGE"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -4.72 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.987305
    INDEX 01 29:52:38
  TRACK 11 AUDIO
    TITLE "いざ、倒れ逝くその時まで..."
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -8.28 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.987183
    INDEX 01 32:39:55
  TRACK 12 AUDIO
    TITLE "Civilization of Magic"
    REM COMMENT "死なばもろとも"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -2.69 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.888946
    INDEX 01 35:26:45
  TRACK 13 AUDIO
    TITLE "The 'Alice in Wonderland' Angel"
    REM COMMENT "星幽剣士／星幽天使"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -5.05 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.965332
    INDEX 01 39:28:34
  TRACK 14 AUDIO
    TITLE "アイリス"
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_GAIN -0.62 dB
    REM REPLAYGAIN_TRACK_PEAK 0.678742
    INDEX 01 42:58:57
```

I found this solution online and it worked:

```
cuebreakpoints *.cue | sed s/\$/0/ | shnsplit -o flac *.wav
```

However, the output file name is just split-track[##].flac, and I need a more descriptive file name, i.e. the title of the piece.

Is there anyway to split the flac using cue that gives me individual flacs with its title as the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering to your last question, which is not related to the title of your post and the outputs you pasted.

**How to give a custom name to `shnsplit` output files ?**

As [written in the man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/shntool/shnsplit.1.en.html#split_mode_options), you can give a custom name pattern with option `-t`. There are several special strings that are recognized. For instance, to name files after track number and title: `-t "%n-%t"`.

EDIT: sorry I missed the main difficulty. Here is another solution.

**How to rename flac files after their tags ?**

If you can’t use the `-t` argument, like in your case, you can still tag and rename the files afterwards.

First, apply tags to your files, based on the cuefile (I hope cuetag can successfully read your file, unlike shnsplit):

```sh
cuetag *.cue *.flac
```

Then, browse the files, read the tags, and rename them accordingly (as described in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589321/use-metaflac-to-rename-flac-files-from-flac-tags-recursively)):

```sh
for a in *.flac; do
TITLE=`metaflac "$a" --show-tag=TITLE | sed s/.*=//g`
TRACKNUMBER=`metaflac "$a" --show-tag=TRACKNUMBER | sed s/.*=//g`
mv "$a" "`printf %02g $TRACKNUMBER`. $TITLE.flac";
done
```

Comment: I already know about the `cuetag` solution due to my research after posting this question, but the filename rename commands are very helpful.